# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to learn how to create a machine learning API with Flask, however, following [this tutorial](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/01/build-api-machine-learning-model-using-flask.html), the following error appears when I type the command `python app.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Breno\Desktop\flask-api\app.py", line 24, in <module>
        model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree'
```

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle as p
import pandas as pd
import json
#from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST'])
def makecalc():
    j_data = request.get_json()

    prediction = np.array2string(model.predict(j_data))

    return jsonify(prediction)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    modelfile = 'models/final_prediction.pickle'    

    model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))

    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: How did you create/save `models/final_prediction.pickle`?

Comment: well, this site has a link to the repository of the original project, so I downloaded the project clone and used this "models / final_prediction.pickle", focusing only on the creation part of the api with Flask.

Answer (score 2):

Pickles are not necessarily compatible across scikit-learn versions so this behavior is expected (and the use case is not supported). For more details, see https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/model_persistence.html#model-persistence. Replace pickle by joblib.
by example :

```
>>> from sklearn import svm
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> clf = svm.SVC()
>>> X, y= datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
SVC()

>>> from joblib import dump, load
>>> dump(clf, open('filename.joblib','wb'))
>>> clf2 = load(open('filename.joblib','rb'))
>>> clf2.predict(X[0:1])
array([0])
>>> y[0]
0
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this issue (perhaps dealing with code written long ago), `sklearn.tree.tree` is now under `sklearn.tree` (as from `v0.24`). This can be see from the import error warning:

```
from sklearn.tree.tree import BaseDecisionTree
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.tree.tree module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.tree. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.tree is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
```

Instead, use:

```
from sklearn.tree import BaseDecisionTree
```

Comment: I consider this the recent answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of `sklearn`. Module `sklearn.tree.tree` is removed since version `0.24`. Most probably, your model has been generated with the older version. Try installing an older version of sklearn:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.20.4
```

Comment: I highly doubt that there ever was such a module, and certainly it does not seem to exist in v0.20: https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.tree

Comment: @desertnaut I couldn't find this module myself. But per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598050/the-sklearn-tree-tree-module-is-deprecated-in-version-0-22-and-will-be-removed-i?noredirect=1&lq=1), there was a warning about its deprecation. It might be some internal module that wasn't documented. And was deprecated and now removed.

Comment: @desertnaut And I guess, [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/tree/tree.py) is the module. Which is not present in the [latest](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/main/sklearn/tree) version.