# import Porter error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am not able to import Porter;  I am facing

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree' error
```

Code:

```
from sklearn_porter import Porter
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-574fff36293e> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn_porter import Porter
      2 
      3 porter = Porter(clf, language='c')
      4 output = porter.export()
      5 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn_porter/__init__.py in <module>
      7 from json import load
      8 
----> 9 from sklearn_porter.Porter import Porter
     10 
     11 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn_porter/Porter.py in <module>
      8 
      9 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
---> 10 from sklearn.tree.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
     11 from sklearn.ensemble.weight_boosting import AdaBoostClassifier
     12 from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree.tree'
```

Comment: This is a version issue, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029751/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-tree-tree).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your version of `sklearn` is recent (0.20 or newer). In this case the import fails. You could downgrade `sklearn`, but this is not suggested. Or you can edit the imports in `sklearn_porter/Porter.py` by hand. Here are the lines to [change](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/pull/81/files).

There is a related pull request on [GitHub](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter/pull/81) to close this issue in the future.