# Import Error: cannot import name 'tree' from 'sklearn.tree'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am on my second day of re-taking Python for the gazillionth time!
I am doing a tutorial on ML in Python, using the following code:

```
import sklearn.tree
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import tree

music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
x = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(x,y)

tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file='music-recommender.dot',
                feature_names=['age','gender'],
                class_names= sorted(y.unique()),
                label='all',
                rounded=True,
                filled=True)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13088/3820271611.py in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
----> 4 from sklearn.tree import tree
      5 
      6 music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')

ImportError: cannot import name 'tree' from 'sklearn.tree' (C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\__init__.py)
```

I've tried to find a solution online, but I don't think it's the version of Python/Anaconda because I literally just installed both. I also don't think it's the *sklearn.tree* since I was able to import *DecisionClassifer*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029751/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-tree-tree

Comment: `from sklearn.tree import tree` In order for that to work, there would have to be a module named `sklearn.tree.tree`, which seems doubtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69453521/3381305) indicates, you're looking at some older code; this is always a risk with programming. But there's another thing you need to know about your code.

First off, [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html) contains several modules, and almost everything you need from it is in one of those. In my experience, most people import things like this:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor   # A regressor class.
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree               # A helpful function.
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error   # An evaluation function.
```

It looks like the tutorial wants something similar to [`plot_tree()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html#sklearn.tree.plot_tree). This new-ish function is much easier to use than the older Graphviz visualization. So unless you really need the DOT file for some reasons, you should be able to do this:

```py
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree

sklearn.tree.plot_tree(model)
```

Bottom line: there will probably be more broken things in that material. So if I were you I'd either make a new environment with a version of `sklearn` matching whatever material you're using... or ditch that material and look for something newer.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot! yeah, I think the tutorial is from 2+ years ago, didn't know things changed that fast!

Answer (score 0):

`from sklearn.tree import tree` looks wrong. Did you mean `from sklearn import tree` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [Scikit Learn Decision Trees Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) you really do not need too much of importing.

It can be done simply as follows:

```
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd

music_data = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])
y = music_data['genre']
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
```